# Is there any log kept of the files I delete?

Tags: delete, 11.10, log

I deleted a folder today while I was thinking I had clicked on another one. 
Is there any log that I can search to find the name of the folder I just deleted?

The files deleted were probably not important (it was a subfolder of a folder I keep movies) so I don't need to recover them - I just need the name of the folder.

In case it matters, the folder used to be on a ntfs-formatted partition that has a bug on my system (or is it in every ntfs out there? I never searched cause I liked it better the way it is now) to not send files to trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, besides sending files to Trash before actually deleting there is no registration of what was deleted.

Comment: It's a pity but well..if i ever need what was there, i'll remember it's name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there are any logs kept about deleted files. (Unless they're just deleted by moving them to the trash folder, in which case they are not yet removed from the system.)

However, there are tools that *may* allow you to browse and even recover the deleted files, along with their file names. In case you've done nothing else with the partition after the files were deleted, these should do a good job.

Probably the most popular one is [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It's available in Ubuntu repositories, so you can get it with `sudo apt-get install testdisk`

Since in your case the files were on NTFS, here's a link to [a guide to browsing an NTFS partition with TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk%3a_undelete_file_for_NTFS).

Comment: Kiitos, but i already tried testdisk and i got too many results and couldn't find out which one was the folder i deleted